# Change style of Wicket Wizard extension

Tags: coding-style, wicket, wizard

how can change the style (css) of the Wicket extension Wizard (org.apache.wicket.extensions.wizard)? Is there a common way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Wizard.css next to Wizard.java.
Just override org.apache.wicket.extensions.wizard.Wizard.addDefaultCssStyle(IHeaderResponse) so that it uses your own .css and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

we can disable the default css by overriding the Wizard constructor in your sub class of the wizard.
ex:

```
public class MyWizard extends Wizard {

public MyWizard(String id)

super(id,false)// by passing the false we can disable the default css

}
```